# Using a Spider chart in dojox. Is it possible to remove the fill and leave only the stroke of the series?

Tags: charts, dojo, web-crawler

I'm using the `dojox/charting/plot2d/Spider` to show a Spider chart and having at least 3 series at a time in the same chart makes it difficult to see the actual strokes that are the important thing there. Is there any way to remove the fill?

I've tried the following but it ends up black.

```
chart.addSeries("test", { data: whatever }, { fill: "transparent" });
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the right option! If you set `seriesFillAlpha` to 0 when adding the Spider plot then the fill doesn't show up.

Example:

```
new Chart(someNode)
    .addPlot("default", {
        type: Spider,
        seriesFillAlpha: 0.1
    });
```

Hope this helps somebody.